# Auto Populate a Grid in Odoo and Error

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Odoo do an Auto Populate a Grid when a user Creating a new information with One2many relations fields?

this is my Example Auto Populate

```
def getCheckListId(self):
    self.env.cr.execute("select 1 employee_id,1 PARAM1,1 PARAM2,1 PARAM3,1 PARAM3,1 PARAM4 from hr_employee_checklist  ")
    checklistTemplates = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    return checklistTemplates
```

And this function will be used as a default in One2ManyFields

```
employee_checklists = fields.One2many('hr.employee_checklist','employee_id', readonly=False,copy=False, default = getCheckListId)
```

But I have an error 
the error is

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Can someone help me with this problem or other ways to populate Grid in Odoo

Comment: why you don't use api methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One2many**

One2many field; the value of such a field is the `recordset` of all the records in `comodel_name` such that the field `inverse_name` is equal to the current record.

**Parameters**

- comodel_name -- name of the target model (string)
- inverse_name -- name of the inverse Many2one field in comodel_name
  (string)
- domain -- an optional domain to set on candidate values on the client
  side (domain or string)
- context -- an optional context to use on the client side when
  handling that field (dictionary)
- auto_join -- whether JOINs are generated upon search through that
  field (boolean, by default False)
- limit -- optional limit to use upon read (integer)

So, One2many fields always contains comodel's reference value, you just need to give ids of that relational field, remaining things will maintain by odoo engine it self.

```
@api.model
def getCheckListId(self):
    return self.env['hr.employee.checklist'].search([]).ids
```